# SFTP logs in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, logs, sftp

Where can I find log messages for sftp?
I want to find all log messages related to sftp-server - file sent, file received.

Answer (score 6):

Please read `man sftp-server`. In that manual page you can read about directive `log_level` which defaults to ERROR. If you set `log_level` to INFO or VERBOSE, transactions will be logged.

So by default, these kind of messages are not logged.

To enable logging edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and look for:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Append `-l INFO` to the line, save and exit. Then restart sshd using `systemctl restart ssh`

Try an sftp action and have a look at `/var/log/auth.log` for messages like:

```
Dec  6 15:11:47 myhost sftp-server[4674]: open "/home/myuser/testfile" flags READ mode 0666
Dec  6 15:11:47 myhost sftp-server[4674]: close "/home/myuser/testfile" bytes read 8 written 0
```

When using `sftp-server` in a `chroot`-ed environment the following also applies:

> On some systems, sftp-server must be able to access /dev/log for
>   logging to work, and use of sftp-server in a chroot configuration
>   therefore requires that syslogd(8) establish a logging socket inside
>   the chroot directory.

By default sftp-server uses `AUTH` as log facility. Check the logging configuration to verify if logging for `AUTH` is configured. For example for `rsyslog`:

```
$ grep auth /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf 
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: I tried doing this. I do not see any kind of messages in the 'auth.log' file

Comment: Please check your logging configuration. Perhaps another logfile is used in your environment.

Comment: How can I check my logging configuration?